# Can the Use of External Data Sources to Enhance GPT Models Raise Legal Concerns?

Tags: chatgpt, gpt, chatgpt-3.5

I recently came across news about GPT-BOT being able to read articles from sources like The New York Times and Financial Times, but I've also heard that The New York Times blocked its use. How does OpenAI collect and use external articles to train their models like GPT, and what are legal considerations surrounding this practice and is this just okay?

Comment: This question is about specific legal matters, which is off-topic on Gen AI. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer. Consider [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Answer (score 1):

> How does OpenAI collect and use external articles to train their models like GPT, and what are legal considerations surrounding this practice and is this just okay?

In the US, we're waiting to see how the ongoing legal actions will end up, e.g. see:

- ['New York Times' considers legal action against OpenAI as copyright tensions swirl](https://www.npr.org/2023/08/16/1194202562/new-york-times-considers-legal-action-against-openai-as-copyright-tensions-swirl)
- [George R.R. Martin, Jodi Picoult and more sue OpenAI: 'Systematic theft on a mass scale'](https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/books/2023/09/20/authors-sue-chat-gpt-alleging-mass-scale-theft/70914409007/)
- [Is it illegal for a firm to train an AI model on a CC BY-SA 4.0 corpus and make a commercial use of it without distributing the model under CC BY-SA?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/91785/31)
- [Generative Artificial Intelligence Creates Copyright Issues](https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/generative-artificial-intelligence-5888315/) has an interesting discussion around fair use.

More generally, there are many ongoing legal actions on the use of data to train genAI model.

Other countries may have a difference stance on this legal matter, e.g. for Japan see [Legal Issues In Generative AI Under Japanese Law](https://www.mondaq.com/copyright/1357690/legal-issues-in-generative-ai-under-japanese-law--copyright).